# HTML displays on the front end of map tabs

Tags: plugins, joomla

I am using the Hotspots map plugin for Joomla. I have contacted support with no response.

The html for the tab title tags appears incorrect, causing "> to appear in the titles, and <span class= to appear when you mouse over the tabs on the front end. It views this way in any browser.
Is there a way to fix this without rewriting the code of the plugin? I searched in all the plugin files and can't seem to find where this is written.

[image]

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Comment: Not going to join us in JSE?